# ускорение заполнения ячеек в excel (используя VBA)

Tags: excel, оптимизация, vba, производительность, запись

Приветствую

Написал макрос для excel (на VBA) который обрабатывает данные и заносит их в таблицу (на отдельном листе).

Таблица довольно большая, поэтому макрос работает относительно значительное время. Мне почему-то кажется, что это связано с тем, что после каждой записи в ячейку excel выполняет какие-то действия по перерисовке листа и именно это значительно снижает скорость работы макроса.

Действительно ли это так? И если да, то как лучше всего оптимизировать процесс?
Я думал про то, чтобы блокировать лист (перерисовка) до тех пор, пока все данные не будут внести, и лишь после этого разблокировать лист.

Прав ли я? И если да, то как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: *как лучше всего оптимизировать процесс?* Вариант 1 - отключить обновление экрана на время внесения изменений (`Application.ScreenUpdating=False`), и не забыть потом включить обратно. Вариант 2 - накопить изменения в двумерном массиве, а потом одной строкой скопировать его в нужный диапазон. Впрочем, можно и то, и другое одновременно.

Comment: первый вариант не помог :(

Comment: http://www.excel-vba.ru/chto-umeet-excel/kak-uskorit-i-optimizirovat-kod-vba/

Comment: @Zhihar, факторов много. Обращение к объектам листа медленное, нужно работать с массивами. Пересчет формул, изменение форматирования...Возможно,  отключение *ScreenUpdating* ставите не в том месте...  Покажите код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень полезную ссылку дал **slippyk**, рекомендую ознакомиться обязательно.

К тому, что там написано, от себя добавлю следующее:

1. Полезно для производительности не только читать/записывать ячейки с помощью двумерного массива. Более универсальный совет: избегать, по возможности, любых обращений в цикле к объектам библиотек VBA. `Worksheet`, `Range`, `Borders` и др. - это всё COM-объекты, а каждый вызов их методов/свойств - дополнительный оверхед.

Соответственно, если записываете ячейки массивом за один вызов `.Range(...).Value = array`, а затем хотите отформатировать таблицу, установив форматы чисел, границы ячеек и др., то обрабатывайте ячейки тоже диапазонами. Если форматирование для разных колонок таблицы должно различаться, обрабатывайте каждую колонку как один диапазон. Но ни в коем случае в больших таблицах не обрабатывайте ячейки по одной.

2. Отключив обновление экрана, обязательно гарантируйте восстановление режима работы Excel, чтобы ошибка при выполнении макроса не привела пользователя к пустому окну приложения. Он будет закрывать Excel через диспетчер задач и нехорошо выражаться в адрес программиста :)  Используйте операторы "On Error".

Ниже прилагаю пример кода, демонстрирующий скорость заполнения листа миллионом значений (таблица 10000 строк на 100 столбцов).
Чтобы запустить код:

- создайте книгу Excel и два листа в ней
- откройте окно редактора VBA
- переименуйте листы в "Sheet_1" и "Sheet_2"
- на листе Sheet_1 можно ввести несколько числовых значений (вводя строку или дату, сможете увидеть впоследствии, как отреагирует макрос на ошибку)
- создайте модуль и вставьте в него код макроса
- выполните макрос (у меня примерно 1.5 сек.) и перейдите в окно Excel, чтобы посмотреть результаты

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum As Long
  Dim iLastRow As Long, iLastCol As Long
  Dim src_data As Variant
  Dim dst_data() As Variant

  ' установка обработчика ошибок
  On Error GoTo lbl_error

  ' отключение функций, способных замедлить или приостановить работу макроса
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  ' чтение исходных данных в двумерный массив Variant
  With Sheet_1
    iLastRow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    iLastCol = .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
    src_data = .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(iLastRow, iLastCol)).Value
  End With

  ' какая-нибудь обработка исходных данных (неважно какая)
  sum = 0
  For i = LBound(src_data, 1) To UBound(src_data, 1)
    For j = LBound(src_data, 2) To UBound(src_data, 2)
      sum = sum + CLng(src_data(i, j))
    Next j
  Next i

  ' формирование выходного массива данных 10 000 * 100 = 1 000 000 значений
  ReDim dst_data(0 To 9999, 0 To 99)

  For i = 0 To 9999
    For j = 0 To 99
      dst_data(i, j) = sum + i + j
    Next j
  Next i

  ' запись выходного массива в место назначения
  With Sheet_2
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(10001, 101)).Value = dst_data
  End With

  ' форматирование выходной таблицы
  With Sheet_2
    ' форматы первых трёх колонок
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(10001, 2)).NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(10001, 4)).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

    ' границы на всю таблицу
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(10001, 101))
      Call .BorderAround(xlContinuous, xlThin)

      With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlHairline
      End With

      With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlHairline
      End With
    End With
  End With

  ' перепрыгнуть блок обработки ошибок
  GoTo lbl_finish

  ' обработчик ошибок
lbl_error:
  Call MsgBox("Ошибка " & CStr(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical)
  On Error Resume Next

  ' восстановить режим работы Excel
lbl_finish:
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  ' показать сформированный лист
  Sheet_2.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Обработчик ошибок не стоит применять без оглядки. Только если уж совсем никак. Нужно проверками в коде обходить возможные ошибки. 2. Отключать события и сообщения нежелательно без необходимости, как и пересчет листа (этого в коде нет). 3. Обновление экрана не обязательно отключать в начале процедуры -
 можно перед строкой, где идет обращение к листу (форматирование, выгрузка данных...)

Comment: **vikktur**, спасибо за комментарий! С 3-м пунктом я полностью согласен, а вот по 1-2 хотелось бы пояснений. Заметного влияния обработчика на скорость я не заметил. Может, подскажете, в каких сценариях "On Error" мешает и чем именно? Насчёт отключения сообщений и событий (DisplayAlerts) - из моего опыта в этом есть смысл: например, при объединении ячеек, содержащих разные значения, можно получить сообщение "В объединенной ячейке сохраняется только...". И ячейки-то объединяются, но незадавленное сообщение приостанавливает работу макроса, пока пользователь не закроет окно сообщения

Comment: вот об этом и писал: в коде нужно предусматривать. Отключите сообщения - и пропустите нужное.*If Merge* -  и поехали дальше. События - отключать, если они обрабатываются и если макрос задевает эти диапазоны. Обработчик ошибок.  Пример: открыть книгу и взять данные из указанного листа. При неправильном пути или отсутствии листа - ошибка. Можно применить обработчик. Но можно проверить путь *Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)* и наличие лиса в семействе *Worksheets*... Не отговариваю от применения обработчика, но и не советую применять везде, где его можно втиснуть.